# Error message when trying to update nokogiri gem

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, middleman

I have an error message when trying to update Nokogiri gem :

> The dependency wdm (~> 0.1.0) will be unused by any of the platforms
>   Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the
>   dependency is only for x86-mswin32, x86-mingw32. To add those
>   platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mswin32
>   x86-mingw32`. The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any
>   of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for
>   ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mswin32, x86-mingw32, java. To
>   add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform
>   x86-mswin32 x86-mingw32 java`. Fetching gem metadata from
>   http://rubygems.org/.............. Fetching gem metadata from
>   http://rubygems.org/.. Resolving dependencies... Using i18n 0.7.0
>   Using json 1.8.3 Using minitest 5.7.0 Using thread_safe 0.3.5 Using
>   tzinfo 1.2.2 Using activesupport 4.1.11 Using addressable 2.3.8 Using
>   execjs 2.5.2 Using autoprefixer-rails 5.2.1 Using sass 3.4.15 Using
>   bootstrap-sass 3.3.5 Using bundler 1.16.0 Using hitimes 1.2.2 Using
>   timers 4.0.1 Using celluloid 0.16.0 Using chunky_png 1.3.4 Using
>   coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1 Using coffee-script 2.4.1 Using
>   multi_json 1.11.1 Using compass-core 1.0.3 Using compass-import-once
>   1.0.5 Using rb-fsevent 0.9.5 Using ffi 1.9.8 Using rb-inotify 0.9.5 Using compass 1.0.3 Using eventmachine 1.0.7 Using http_parser.rb
>   0.6.0 Using em-websocket 0.5.1 Using erubis 2.7.0 Using font-awesome-sass 4.2.2 Using tilt 1.4.1 Using haml 4.0.6 Using hike
>   1.2.3 Using uber 0.0.13 Using hooks 0.4.0 Using htmlcompressor 0.2.0 Using thor 0.19.1 Using jquery-middleman 3.1.2 Using kramdown 1.7.0
>   Using listen 2.10.1 Using padrino-support 0.12.5 Using padrino-helpers
>   0.12.5 Using rack 1.6.4 Using rack-test 0.6.3 Using middleman-core 3.3.12 Using sprockets 2.12.3 Using sprockets-helpers 1.1.0 Using sprockets-sass 1.3.1 Using middleman-sprockets 3.4.2 Using uglifier
>   2.7.1 Using middleman 3.3.12 Using middleman-blog 3.5.3 Using net-ssh 2.9.2 Using net-sftp 2.1.2 Using ptools 1.3.2 Using middleman-deploy 1.0.0 Using middleman-disqus 1.1.0 Using rack-livereload 0.3.15 Using middleman-livereload 3.1.1 Using middleman-minify-html 3.4.1 Using
>   middleman-protect-emails 0.3.1 Using mini_portile2 2.3.0 Fetching
>   nokogiri 1.8.2 (was 1.6.6.4) Installing nokogiri 1.8.2 (was 1.6.6.4)
>   with native extensions Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build
>   gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2/ext/nokogiri
> ```
>
> /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r
>   ./siteconf20180130-47766-zngdwi.rb extconf.rb checking if the C
>   compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create
>   Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries
>   and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
>   need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:   --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
>     --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>     --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
>     --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
>     --ruby=/usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>     --help  --clean
>   /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in
>   `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
>   (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first.   from
>   /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in`
>   block in try_compile'    from
>   /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:522:in
>   `with_werror'     from
>   /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in`
>   try_compile'     from extconf.rb:138:in `nokogiri_try_compile'   from
>   extconf.rb:162:in`block in add_cflags'   from
>   /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:619:in
>   `with_cflags'     from extconf.rb:161:in`add_cflags'     from
>   extconf.rb:410:in `'
>
> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>
> /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.8.2/mkmf.log
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.2
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.8.2/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.2), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'`
>   succeeds before bundling.
>
> In Gemfile:   nokogiri

Comment: If you're using MAC OS you need to install xcode first. Double-check if xcode was removed.

Comment: @WillNguyen, xCode and the command line tools need to be installed. And xcode-select -p should point to an existing xcode.app path.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Indeed xcode has been removed, maybe when I uptaded macos to the latest version ?

So Nokogiri has been updated.

I still have two issue :
1) I need to replace in the Gemfile https by http due to SSL certificate problem. Do you know how to fix that ?

Comment: 2) During the update I had this message :
The dependency wdm (~> 0.1.0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mswin32, x86-mingw32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mswin32 x86-mingw32`.
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused [...] Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mswin32, x86-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mswin32 x86-mingw32 java`.

Answer (score 2):

This helped me on **Ubuntu runnung on WSL**:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev`

From [official Nokogiri installation instructions](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html)

For **Mac OS**, it suggests:

1. First, make sure you have the latest version of RubyGems and xcode commandline tools:
2. Run:

`gem update --system`

`xcode-select --install`

3. Then install nokogiri:

`gem install nokogiri`

There are more troubleshooting tips on that page.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help